Photon propagation paradox, what am I missing?
I've seen photons and EM waves be described like so "Electromagnetic waves can be imagined as a self-propagating transverse oscillating wave of electric and magnetic fields."
So if we have a Time1, Location1 and could measure the field we have some variable x representing the field (like the values of the E and H), and at Time2, Location2, a bit forward both in time and space, we measure the EM field and call it variable y.  Thus y depends on x, correct? --edit: use however many nearby in time and space x variables you need to calculate y or a set of y assuming this wave is the only one in the area.
Photons/EM waves only add/subtract when they cross but otherwise pass through without changing their own characteristics.  So if the wave passes through another (but not at Time2,Location2) y will still be y.
So if we imagine another wave intersecting the first at Time1,Location1, the value there would no longer be x, it would be x + the value contributed by the second wave.  So now I'm confused, because y no longer depends on x.  This is why I'm calling it a paradox.
So that I can write an example in text, pretend for a moment we simplify and replace the actual math of propagation with a single integer and a wave just adds one at each time-distance step.
Wave by itself: 1 2 3 4 5
Wave after another wave intersects, adding 2 to 3:  1 2 5 6 7
If the 5th depends on the 4th and the 4th depends on the 3rd, I expect the 5th position to be 7, but it will be 5 regardless of interaction with other waves.  Back to reality, is this because the math of adding the waves works out to produce the same result (minus the actual points of intersection) or is there another mechanism causing the propagation?
Quoting The Photon,

Then the E and H vectors associated with the wave coming from the first source will contribute to the wave continuing to propagate on to location 2, while the components associated with the second (interfering) wave won't, and the fields at location 2 will depend only on the components at location 1 caused by the first wave, just as we expect.

I don't expect that is the problem I'm having.  How can location 2 be identical in both scenarios when location 1 is different in both scenarios?  If it's self-propagating, the excitation in the EM field is not what's causing it unless the math just works out the same regardless of adding that second wave.

The assertion that "y no longer depends on x" is false. It still does. A wave is not a confined object; it is a function on the entire spacetime.

@VincentThacker But the value at the location is no longer x because of the summation of the two EM waves in the scenario with two waves.  Take as many points in spacetime as you want, y is somehow the same in both scenarios, but when there are two waves, many of the points in spacetime will be different because we've added/subtracted the waves.  So clearly y is not dependent on x.


Photons/EM waves only add/subtract when they cross but otherwise pass through without changing their own characteristics.

Correct.

You can't cancel them like you can with sound.

Incorrect. The behavior of sound waves is the same. Two sound waves in the same place interfere (add or subtract pressure and velocity components) but don't otherwise change each other's characteristics.
You can only "cancel" one sound wave with another at in a limited space. If you cancel it (produce destructive interference) in one area, you will also make it louder (produce constructive interference) somewhere else.

So if we imagine another wave intersecting the first at Time1,Location1, the value there would no longer be x, it would be x + the value of created by the second wave. So now I'm confused, because y no longer depends on x.

You have to consider both the electric and magnetic field components. When the two waves intersect at location 1, both the electric and magnetic components superpose (add up). If the two waves are not propagating in the same direction, then even if their E vectors point in the same direction, their H (magnetic field) vectors will not.
Then the E and H vectors associated with the wave coming from the first source will contribute to the wave continuing to propagate on to location 2, while the components associated with the second (interfering) wave won't, and the fields at location 2 will depend only on the components at location 1 caused by the first wave, just as we expect.
We wouldn't be able to predict this from observing the EM field only at one specific spot (location 1), but the idea that we can predict the wave at location 2 only from observations at location 1 isn't a fundamental fact of electromagnetics, it's only a helpful circumstance that applies in very simple cases (when there's only wave present). We likely could predict the field at location 2 if we could also sample a second location (call it location 1a) nearby but not exactly the same as location 1.

Username checks out.

I can't quote in comments for some reason.  I have edited my question and I think it'll be more clear if you would please have another look
